# Linq select object from list depending on objects attribute

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects

```
class Answer
{
   bool correct;
}

List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();
```

Is there a way in linq for me to select an object depending on its attribute?

So far I have

```
Answer answer = Answers.Single(a => a == a.Correct);
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First, [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) throws an exception if there is more than one element satisfying the criteria. Second, your criteria should only check if the `Correct` property is `true`. Right now, you are checking if `a` is equal to `a.Correct` (which will not even compile).

You can also consider using [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) (which will throw if there are no such elements), or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) (which will return `null` for a reference type if there isn't such element), or `Where` followed by `ToList` (which will return all elements which satisfy the criteria):

```
// this will either find a single correct answer,
// or throw an exception if there are no correct answers
// or if there is more than one correct answer
var correct = answers.Single(a => a.Correct);

// this will either find a single correct answer,
// or return null if there are no correct answers,
// or throw an exception if there is more than one correct answer
var correct = answers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Correct);

// this will return the first correct answer,
// or throw an exception if there are no correct answers
var correct = answers.First(a => a.Correct); 

// this will return the first correct answer, 
// or null if there are no correct answers
var correct = answers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Correct); 

// this will return a list containing all answers which are correct,
// or an empty list if there are no correct answers
var allCorrect = answers.Where(a => a.Correct).ToList();
```

Answer (score 18):

I assume you are getting an exception because of [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx). Your list may have more than one answer marked as correct, that is why `Single` will throw an exception use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx), or [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx);

```
Answer answer = Answers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Correct);
```

Also if you want to get list of all items marked as correct you may try:

```
List<Answer> correctedAnswers =  Answers.Where(a => a.Correct).ToList();
```

If your desired result is `Single`, then the mistake you are doing in your query is comparing an item with the bool value. Your comparison

```
a == a.Correct
```

is wrong in the statement. 
Your single query should be:

```
Answer answer = Answers.Single(a => a.Correct == true);
```

Or shortly as:

```
Answer answer = Answers.Single(a => a.Correct);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The single method is EXACTLY what I've been looking for for a few days!!

Answer (score 5):

Your expression is never going to evaluate.

You are comparing `a` with a property of `a`.

`a` is of type Answer.  `a.Correct`, I'm guessing is a boolean.

Long form:-

```
Answer = answer.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Correct == true);
```

Short form:-

```
Answer = answer.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Correct);
```

Answer (score 2):

if `a.Correct` is a `bool` flag for the correct answer then you need.

```
Answer answer = Answers.Single(a => a.Correct);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this?

```
var correctAnswer = Answers.First(a => a.Correct);
```

You can use single by typing :

```
var correctAnswer = Answers.Single(a => a.Correct);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course!

Use `FirstOrDefault()` to select the first object which matches the condition:

```
Answer answer = Answers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Correct);
```

Otherwise use `Where()` to select a subset of your list:

```
var answers = Answers.Where(a => a.Correct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to fix here:

1. No parenthesis in class declaration
2. Make the "correct" property as public
3. And then do the selection

Your code will look something like this

```
List<Answer> answers = new List<Answer>();
/* test
answers.Add(new Answer() { correct = false });
answers.Add(new Answer() { correct = true });
answers.Add(new Answer() { correct = false });
*/
Answer answer = answers.Single(a => a.correct == true);
```

and the class

```
class Answer
{
   public bool correct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Answers = Answers.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(x => x.First());
```

This will select each unique object by email